# Use intel AVX with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jvm, avx, avx512

We have a new cluster with intel AVX 512 CPUs. We did research about the subject without result.
We would like to know if a spark job is able to run with AVX natively to do processing on DataFrames objects, or if we have to change the code to allow the JVM to use it, or if it's totally useless. Our spark app are codded with scala. 
Most of our jobs are DataFrames objects processing and algorithms. 
Thank's in advance for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will depend on a couple of things.

AVX512 support was added to OpenJDK in JDK 9 (see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8076276), so you would need to be running on JDK 9 or later.  To enable this explicitly you will need to add the command line flag `-XX:UseAVX=3`.

However, how much this gets used will depend a lot on the way your code works and how the JIT compiler is able to use vectorisation.  At Azul (who I work for), we have replaced the C2 JIT in our Zing JVM with our Falcon JIT.  This is based on the LLVM compiler project and is able to use vectorisation in more complex cases than are typically recognised by C2.

Comment: Just for the record - Spark doesn't support JDK9 or later yet.

Answer (score 0):

As @Speakjava noticed at this moment using SIMD instructions in Spark code is not feasible, because AVX512 was added in Java 9 which is not supported by Spark yet.  But there will be radical changes in the coming years - [Project Panama](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/panama/). Once the vector API is complete, projects like Spark will be able to profit enormously from it. You can follow up [JEP-338](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/338) for upcoming changes.

If you are interested in leveraging low-level Intel's API for gaining a performance, boost take a look at Intel's library [Data Analytics Acceleration Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Analytics_Acceleration_Library). Intel states that it can bring the performance boost for `MLlib`. It has analogs of some classes from Spark - `org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.{PCA, PCAModel} -> daal_for_mllib.{PCA, PCAModel}` - a detailed example is [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-data-analytics-acceleration-library-intel-daal-how-to-use-with-apache-spark).